# Unable to find content provider for username [myUsername] when uploading app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

After I archive my iOS app and I want to upload it to the App Store, I get this message

[image]

This is the log:

```
2015-12-08 08:11:13 +0000  The store submission configuration response failed with errors: (  
    "Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=1013 \"Unable to find content provider for username [myUsername].\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to find content provider for username [myUsername]., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to find content provider for username [myUsername]., NSLocalizedFailureReason=iTunes Store operation failed.}"  
), warnings: (  
), info messages: (  
).  
2015-12-08 08:11:15 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=1013 "Unable to find content provider for username [myUsername]." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to find content provider for username [myUsername]., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to find content provider for username [myUsername]., NSLocalizedFailureReason=iTunes Store operation failed.}
```

I tried uploading the .ipa with the Application Loader, but there it gives me the same error when logging in.

Comment: Looks like an iTunes Connect bug. File a bug report and contact Apple support.

Comment: Try to upload from Application loader.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer from Apples Dev Forum:

*In general, you can't archive if:

- a simulator is selected instead of a device
- there is an error when building
- you haven't staged your app as 'Waiting for Upload' in iTunes Connect
- you've recently renewed your apple developer account, and not yet updated the provisions to reflect that activity*

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27795

Comment: none of these options apply for my case unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

i think recreate your CSR file.may be dont find your account in key chain.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a problem with your Distribution Certificate. Create One distribution cert by uploading csr.

Answer (score 0):

It's for sure because of invalid key pair or distribution certificate. To debug this

1.choose validate before submitting archive (check if validation is succesfull):
[image]

2. Check on this screenis provisioning profile is the one you want to sign the app
3. Log to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com) and check if your certificate not expired

I'm guessing this will be wrong provisioning profile or **expired** one. If that will be true, you need to renew it in developer center.

Comment: already renewed it (multiple times), generated new certificates from the machine itself, double checked everything but still gives the same error. funny thing is that it has no problems when i upload it with an member-account. (I want to upload it with the agent-account)